# Binding UIImageView invalid cast in Xamarin after upgrade

Tags: c#, ios, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I recently tried to recompile a project that had been working in a newer version of Xamarin.  The project compiles, but crashes on the device with an invalid cast exception.

System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

The crash occurs in designer generated code:

```
        [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("turnOnAnimation")]
    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImageView turnOnAnimation {
        get {
            object test = this.GetNativeField ("turnOnAnimation");
            **this.__mt_turnOnAnimation = ((MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImageView)(this.GetNativeField("turnOnAnimation")));**
            return this.__mt_turnOnAnimation;
        }
        set {
            this.__mt_turnOnAnimation = value;
            this.SetNativeField("turnOnAnimation", value);
        }
    }
```

Studying the return from GetNativeField, I seem to be getting a UIView instead of a UIImageView back:

[image: Watch Value]

But the outlet in the XIB is connected to a UIImageView.

[image: Outlets]

To my knowledge this code was working fine with earlier versions.  Has something changed in recent versions or should I be doing something differently?

Comment: Your return value _is_ a `UIImageView`. The debugger clearly shows `<UIImageView: ...`

Comment: Yes, the value of the object indicates that it is the UIImageView--but the type of the return value is the parent UIView and it won't allow me to cast it.  It's very odd.  Sorry, I should have included the column headers in the image.  I will update it.

Comment: I also just added the line of code to my question that shows how I am setting the watched value 'test'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional testing showed:

1) This problem occurred on an iPod touch running iOS version 7.1.1

2) The problem did not occur in the simulator running iOS 8.1 (any iOS platform)

3) The problem did not occur on an iPhone running 8.1.2

4) Upgrading the iPod touch to iOS 8.1.3 resolved the issue.

I conclude this was either an iOS bug or an incompatibility between current Xamarin tooling and the older version of iOS.